# Equation alignment with varying number of columns

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, alignat

How do I align an optimization statement where the number of columns varies in each row? I'm trying to align the summation symbols, equation signs within the "subject to" section, and any "for all" statements. There must be a way to do this but I haven't found it yet. Too much space is being placed in front of the equal signs in the second row onwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
    \text{Minimize} \quad
    &\sum_{i} t_i + t_j + t_k + t_m \\
    %
    \text{subject to}\quad
    &\sum_r Y_r &&= p \quad \\
    %
    &\sum_r X_{qr} &&= 1 &&\text{for all $q$}\\
    %
    &\sum_r Z_{ty} &&= 1 &&\text{for all $t$}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your preamble part? It may be part of the solution or problem, which packages you use. Thanks

Comment: @MS-SPO added preamble for clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use a `\mathrlap` directive (provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, a superset of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package) to "hide" the `t_i + t_j + t_k + t_m` part from the remaining equations; see the upper half of the following screenshot.

Speaking for myself, I don't think much that is useful is achieved by aligning the `=` symbols in rows 2 thru 4. Getting rid of that alignment criterion may be preferable; see the lower half of the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathrlap' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
    \text{Minimize\quad}
    &\sum_{i} \mathrlap{t_i + t_j + t_k + t_m} \\
    %
    \text{subject to\quad}
    &\sum_r Y_r &&= p  \\
    %
    &\sum_r X_{qr} &&= 1 &\quad&\text{for all $q$}\\
    %
    &\sum_y Z_{ty} &&= 1 &&\text{for all $t$}
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    \text{Minimize\quad}
    &\sum_{i} \mathrlap{t_i + t_j + t_k + t_m} \\
    %
    \text{subject to\quad}
    &\sum_r Y_r = p  \\
    %
    &\sum_r X_{qr} = 1 &\quad&\text{for all $q$}\\
    %
    &\sum_y Z_{ty} = 1 &&\text{for all $t$}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree that aligning on the equal sign is unnecessary in this example but I wanted the possibility of doing so. I found another solution using \span but I prefer your method

Answer (score 5):

Mico's solution seems more elegant but another solution that I found is using \span to "ignore" unwanted anchors as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
    \text{Minimize} \quad
    &\sum_{i} t_i + t_j + t_k + t_m \span\span \span\span\\
    %
    \text{subject to}\quad
    &\sum_r Y_r &&= p \span\span\\
    %
    &\sum_r X_{qr} &&= 1 &&\quad\text{for all $q$}\\
    %
    &\sum_r Z_{ty} &&= 1 &&\quad\text{for all $t$}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It can be done easily with the `\IEEEeqnarraymulticol` command from the [`IEEEtrantools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools) package. Appendix F of [this documentation](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) covers the `IEEEeqnarray` environment. With this environment, it's very convenient to manage multiline equations. [Here](https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf) is another document that covers this environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rlCll}
    \text{Minimize\quad}   & \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{4}{l}{\sum_{i} t_i + t_j + t_k + t_m}\\%
    \text{subject to\quad} & \sum_r Y_r    &=& p & \\%
                           & \sum_r X_{qr} &=& 1 & \quad\text{for all $q$}\\%
                           & \sum_y Z_{ty} &=& 1 & \quad\text{for all $t$}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```